# Evaluate integral using Gamma function $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

Given :  $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} \mathrm{d}x$$

How do I start?

Comment: I would split the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ to $3/2\pi$ and $2\pi$ and use the symmetry properties.

Comment: What are $l$ and $m$ supposed to be; integers, reals, complex?

Comment: l, m are reals..

Comment: When $l,m\notin \frac12\mathbb Z$, then which complex value of $(\cos x)^{2l-1}$ and $(\sin x)^{2m-1}$ do you choose?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $\:l, m\ge 1$, and taking into account that both exponents are odd, you can use any of the substitutions:
$$\begin{cases}
u=\cos x,\\
\mathrm d u=-\sin x\,\mathrm dx
\end{cases}\hspace5em\begin{cases}
u=\sin x,\\
\mathrm d u=\cos x\,\mathrm dx
\end{cases}\qquad $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need $2l, 2m \in \mathbb Z$ or $(\cos x)^{2l-1}$ and $(\sin x)^{2m-1}$ won't always be defined. However, as it will turn out, if $m\in \mathbb Z$ or $l\in \mathbb Z$, the integral will be 0 because of the symmetries of trygonometric functions.

Before you make the substitution mentioned by Bernard, you'll first need to divide the integral into two intervals, so that the substitution was alllowed, for example:
\begin{align} I &=\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx =\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx + \\
&\quad + \int_\pi^{3\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx + \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx = \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx + \int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos (\pi-x))^{2l-1}(\sin (\pi-x))^{2m-1} dx + \\
&\quad + \int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos (\pi+x))^{2l-1}(\sin (\pi+x))^{2m-1} dx + \int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos (2\pi-x))^{2l-1}(\sin (2\pi-x))^{2m-1} dx = \\
&= \big(1-(-1)^{2l}-(-1)^{2m}+(-1)^{2l+2m}\big)\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx = \\
&= \big(1-(-1)^{2l}\big)\big(1-(-1)^{2m}\big)\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2l-1}(\sin x)^{2m-1} dx  \end{align}
Then you can make substitution $\sin x=u$, $\cos x\, dx = du$, $\cos^2 x = 1- u^2$:
$$I = \big(1-(-1)^{2l}\big)\big(1-(-1)^{2m}\big)\int_{0}^1 (1-u^2)^{l-1}u^{2m-1}du$$ 
Finally you make substitution $u^2=t$ to get to the Beta function integral:
\begin{align} I &= \big(1-(-1)^{2l}\big)\big(1-(-1)^{2m}\big) \frac12\int_{0}^1 (1-t)^{m-1}t^{l-1}du = \\
&= \big(1-(-1)^{2l}\big)\big(1-(-1)^{2m}\big) \frac{\Gamma(l)\Gamma(m)}{2\Gamma(l+m)}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For $a,b$ real, when splitting to the 4 intervals $[0,\pi/2]$,$[\pi/2,\pi]$,$[\pi,3\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$ the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{a}(x) \sin^{b}(x) \, {\rm d}x &= \left(1+(-1)^{a}+(-1)^{b}+(-1)^{a+b}\right) \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{a}(x) \sin^{b}(x) \, {\rm d}x \\ 
&\stackrel{u=\sin^2(x)}{=} \left(1+(-1)^{a}+(-1)^{b}+(-1)^{a+b}\right) \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \left(1-u\right)^{\frac{a-1}{2}} u^{\frac{b-1}{2}} \, {\rm d}u \\
&=\frac{\left(1+(-1)^{a}\right)\left(1+(-1)^{b}\right)}{2} \, B\left(\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{b+1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
where $B$ is the Beta function, and you need to make a choice for the principal branch of the negative root.